# Matlab Looping Issue for counting similarity score

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have 3 sets of data (AA,B1 and C1) with different lenght and size. The purpose of my code is to be able to count for the similarity score between the data for example the similarity score between AA and B1, AA and C1, B1 and C1. So below is my code that should be able to calculate the similarity score but there is a bit of problem in looping. Only the highest value is select for each pair of data of different length. The output should be AA-B1: 0.2226, AA-C1: 0.2037 and B1-C1: 0.1111 that represent similarity score for each pair.

In reality the output for my code especially `max_val{i}` is supposed according to the size of pairs. For example pairs with size 1 x 2 should have one value in `max_val` output instead of three. Thanks.

```
A1={[4,3,4,3,3]};
A2={[3,1,2,4]};
A3={[1,2,4]};
AA=[A1,A2,A3];
B1={[2,2,4,4]};
C1={[4,4,4,3,2,2]};

set={[AA],[B1],[C1]};
comb_set=nchoosek(set,2); %combinations of two sets

for h=1:size(comb_set,1)
comb_pair=comb_set(h,:)';
sets=comb_pair;

cat=horzcat(sets{:});
c=reshape(repmat(sets{1},numel(sets{2}),1),numel(sets{1})*numel(sets{2}),1);
d=repmat(sets{2}(:),length(sets{1}),1);
pairs=[c d];
ind=cellfun(@numel,pairs(:,1)) > cellfun(@numel,pairs(:,2));
pairs(ind,[1 2]) = pairs(ind,[2 1]) %possible pairs of the row of subset
p=cell(size(pairs,1),1);

for i=1:size(pairs,1)
%the two vectors
[a,b]=deal(pairs{i,:});
%sliding window indices, and compute the sum
idx=hankel(1:numel(a),numel(a):numel(b));
count_minus{i}=bsxfun(@minus,b(idx.'),a);  %count minus between pairs
count_total{i}=numel(a)+numel(b);  %count total
count_intersect{i}=sum(count_minus{i}'==0)';  %count no. of intersection
union{i}=count_total{i}-count_intersect{i};  %union
subset{i}=count_intersect{i}./union{i}; %subset each pair similarity score
max_val{i}=max(subset{i}) %maximum similarity score
bsum=cellfun(@(x) sum(x),max_val);
total{i}=sum(bsum~=0);
average=sum(bsum) / total{i}
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 for loops for `i` and `h` and use `max_val{i}` in the inner loop. What this means is that the same `max_val` cell structure will be used for every value of `h` - in this case `size(comb_set,1)=3`. For every iteration of `h` the `max_val{i}` defined in the previous iteration will be overwritten. Since in the the first and the second run `size(pairs,1)=3` the cell will have a length of 3. In the last one `size(pairs,1)=1`. The cell will still have length 3 but you will just overwrite the first element - you can look at the output of the code you provided and see that the last two elements are equal to the last two of the previous `h` iteration. You need to define `max_val` differently. You could define an array to keep the max values in the `i` loop and write it to `max_values{h}` for example.

When you have errors like this it's easier to generate a minimal working example and check what's wrong. This code is quite difficult to read, also because of missing indents. CTRL+A and CTRL+I make your life much easier.